# The program interprets the other part of the code outside the method

Tags: java

I have this method for reservation flight:

```
public void reserveFlight(ArrayList<Flights> flights) {

    System.out.println("Upisite ID leta kako biste ga rezervisali!");

    int userChoice = scanner.nextInt();

    for (Flights flight : flights) {
        if (userChoice == flight.getFlightId())
            System.out.println("Rezervisali ste let za: " + flight.getTo()
                    + " od " + flight.getFrom() + ". Cena za biznis klasu je: " + flight.getBusinessClassPrice() + "$");
    }
    String yesNo = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Da li imate promo kod? (yes / no ): ");
    if (yesNo.contains("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Unesite vas promo kod: ");
        String promoCode = scanner.nextLine();
        for (Flights flight : flights) {
            if (promoCode.equals(flight.getPromoCode())) {
                System.out.println("Ostvarili ste popust od 10%");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Vas promo kod nije validan.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this in my main method: *In case number 5 is that method*

```
 while (true) {
        int choice = scanner.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                for (Passengers passengers : passengersArrayList) {//printing array elements one below the other
                    System.out.println(passengers);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                for (Flights flights : flightsArrayList) { //printing array elements one below the other
                    System.out.println(flights);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                passengersControllerImpl.addNewPassenger(passengersArrayList); //adding a new passenger
                break;
            case 4:
                flightsControllerImpl.addNewFlights(flightsArrayList); //adding a new flight
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("--- Available flights ---");
                for (Flights flights : flightsArrayList) {
                    System.out.println(flights);
                }
                passengersControllerImpl.reserveFlight(flightsArrayList);
                break;
            case 6:
                showMenu(); //showing options to the user
                break;
            case 7:
                return; //program shutdown
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input!");

        }

    }
```

Messages and variables are not on English but that is not important.

When I run the program, it throws me a list of options, that's okay, I choose option five and it shows me a list of flights, that's okay, Then I choose the flight I will book And it works, Now the program asks me if I have a promo code, if I have a letter yes if I don't I have a letter no:

```
System.out.println("Da li imate promo kod? (yes / no ): ");
    if (yesNo.contains("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Unesite vas promo kod: ");
        String promoCode = scanner.nextLine();
        for (Flights flight : flights) {
            if (promoCode.equals(flight.getPromoCode())) {
                System.out.println("Ostvarili ste popust od 10%");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Vas promo kod nije validan.");
            }
        }
    }
```

After I type no or yes, it doesn't matter, program give me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
```

And send me to this line of code:

```
int choice = scanner.nextInt();
```

This means that I entered the wrong entry in my switch case, because he expects numbers.

Why won't my program continue with the method and this piece of code after asking me for promo code?

```
System.out.println("Da li imate promo kod? (yes / no ): ");
    if (yesNo.contains("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Unesite vas promo kod: ");
        String promoCode = scanner.nextLine();
        for (Flights flight : flights) {
            if (promoCode.equals(flight.getPromoCode())) {
                System.out.println("Ostvarili ste popust od 10%");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Vas promo kod nije validan.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Also now I deleted this part of code:

```
System.out.println("Da li imate promo kod? (yes / no ): ");
    if (yesNo.contains("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Unesite vas promo kod: ");
        String promoCode = scanner.nextLine();
        for (Flights flight : flights) {
            if (promoCode.equals(flight.getPromoCode())) {
                System.out.println("Ostvarili ste popust od 10%");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Vas promo kod nije validan.");
            }
        }
```

that is, code that does not work when I run the program and added this just for debugging:

```
String yesNo = scanner.nextLine();

if(yesNo.contains("s")){
        System.out.println("aaa");
    }else{
        System.out.println("eee");
    }
```

and the program prints me "eee" right away. it does not give me the option to enter a word even though it is in the code to enter

Also when i comment first part of code, this:

```
/*  System.out.println("Upisite ID leta kako biste ga rezervisali!");

    int userChoice = scanner.nextInt();

    for (Flights flight : flights) {
        if (userChoice == flight.getFlightId())
            System.out.println("Rezervisali ste let za: " + flight.getTo()
                    + " od " + flight.getFrom() + ". Cena za biznis klasu je: " + flight.getBusinessClassPrice() + "$");
    }*/
```

Second part works fine, so idk really now

Okey I notice one more thing,

On this part of code:

```
 for (Flights flight : flights) {
        if (userChoice == flight.getFlightId())
            System.out.println("Rezervisali ste let za: " + flight.getTo()
                    + " od " + flight.getFrom() + ". Cena za biznis klasu je: " + flight.getBusinessClassPrice() + "$");
    } //If a delete this curly brace, second part of code works, just print each souts four time because I have 4 flights and etc.
```